# How to avoid to loop JavaScript and C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I think there are better way to do this 
loop for mark in map.

```
var markers = [];
@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <text>
markers.push({
    "title": "@item.Name",
    "lat": "@item.latitude",
    "lng": "@item.longitude",
    "description": "@item.ville"
});
</text>

}
```

Second 
display more information

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ville)
        </td>
```

Comment: Why did you tag this c#? What are you trying to do?

Comment: is project web application asp.net